# How to insert data into a binary file with an hex editor in ubuntu?

Tags: binary

Lets say I have a binary file called file.dat that contains the data "James is a good boy".

Lets now say I want to insert the data " not " at the 8th index of file.dat, So that file.dat

will be "James is not a good boy". How do I do this with an hex editor in ubuntu?

Comment: Really, all files are "binary files" - in your example, does your file contain the ASCII string *James is a good boy* embedded between other non-ASCII bytes, or is the string itself encoded in some other way?

Comment: "in your example, does your file contain the ASCII string James is a good boy embedded between other non-ASCII bytes"                                                               Yes it does.

Comment: If the "binary" file contains structured data (e.g. `tar` file), you'll break (render unusable)  the file if you add bytes in the middle.

Comment: Hex editors don't work like text editors; you can't just insert extra arbitrary bytes. Can you [edit] your post and explain what you're trying to do, and why? It could be that there's a better solution than using a hex editor.

Comment: What kind of file is this? In most files that aren't plain text, you shouldn't do this, because you'll probably break the file if you add or remove a random number of bytes at random point in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Install Bless:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bless
```

Bless hex editor (hexadecimal editor) is a cross platform application available for major operating systems like Linux, Microsoft Windows, MacOS.

Can open any number windows using Tab.

You can quickly find for some content and replace it.

We have advance level of copy and paste feature in Bless Hex editor (hexadecimal editor).

You can use Bless best hex editor to edit large number of data files and also block devices.

One of the best part of this application is you can get more features as per your need by installing required plugins.

By default you can export data in .txt and .html format but for more other formats you can use plugins.

Comment: So I can't actually insert a character between two characters using an hex editor? Is that what you're trying to say by not actually answering my question?

Comment: @Emmanuel: you can edit any file without problems, you just have to know perfectly the ASCII character table to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

If the data was really visible in the file as you indicated, you would ultimately be able to edit it with vi editor or sed and just make the change to add the "not" in there.

Example:

```
sed -e "s/James is a good boy/James is not a good boy/g" file.dat > newfile.dat
```

But without knowing a real life example of what you are trying to do, it's hard to advise without damaging your file and rendering it useless. For example, your "James" line in a hex editor would actually look like this: `614a 656d 2073 7369 6120 6720 6f6f 2064 6f62 0a79`

You would be adding three hex characters plus spaces in there: `6e20 746f 0a20`

But if this was originally a binary file used by a specific program (I'm thinking Ufile or other app), the format of the file may no longer be synchronized because your editing pushed five characters too far to the right.

Real life example:
I receive EDI files that are in a very old format known as COMPORD. These are files that have strict standards for where each piece of information is stored in the file. And each line can only be 80 chars long. If I were to change some data in there by adding five characters, the rest of the line would be in the wrong spot for the software to read. And that line would be 85 chars long and so would get cut off or rejected.

This is why it is important to know what the program that is reading that file.dat is expecting to see in each line of your index. If it is variable length and contains delimiters, then yes you can probably edit it to add the extra chars. If it is fixed length or each line contains fields that are padded with spaces or other ASCII codes, then you will corrupt the data file.